# Is there an easier way to make a randomised quiz?

Tags: python

I need to make a randomised quiz for an assignment, and have been trying for a long time. I came up with this and its the only one I can get to work:

```
import random

q = ["What is the capital of England?",
     "What is the capital of France?",
     "What is the capital of Germany?"]

random.shuffle(q)
qN = 1
score = 0

while qN < 4:
    if q[0] == "What is the capital of England?":
        Cans = "London"
        print("\n\nQuestion " + str(qN) + "\n")
        ans = input(q[0] + "\n")
        if ans == Cans:
            print("\nCorrect")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nIncorrect")
        del q[0]
        qN += 1
    elif q[0] == "What is the capital of France?":
        Cans = "Paris"
        print("\n\nQuestion " + str(qN) + "\n")
        ans = input(q[0] + "\n")
        if ans == Cans:
            print("\nCorrect")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nIncorrect")
        del q[0]
        qN += 1
    elif q[0] == "What is the capital of Germany?":
        Cans = "Berlin"
        print("\n\nQuestion " + str(qN) + "\n")
        ans = input(q[0] + "\n")
        if ans == Cans:
            print("\nCorrect")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nIncorrect")
        del q[0]
        qN += 1

print("You scored", score, "out of 3 correct!")
```

The way I did it seems way too long and I'm sure that there's a much simpler way but I just can't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You could use a dict to store your question/answers

Comment: Create a class to represent each question, create an instance of the class for each question, then randomly assign question order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start would be to group your questions and answers using a list of tuples:

```py
quiz = [
    ("What is the capital of England?", "London"),
    ("What is the capital of France?", "Paris"),
    ("What is the capital of Germany?", "Berlin")
]
```

Then, instead of a `while` loop, use a `for` loop:

```py
random.shuffle(quiz)
score = 0

# questions and answers are now paired up
for question, answer in quiz:
    print(question)
    user_answer = input("Answer: ")

    if user_answer.strip() == answer:
        score += 1
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")


# Use an f-string to format the score and number of questions
print(f"You scored {score} out of {len(quiz)}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

#### Define your questions:

```py
import random

questions = {
    "What is the capital of England?": "London",
    "What is the capital of France?": "Paris",
    "What is the capital of Germany?": "Berlin"
}
```

#### Shuffle the questions, set initial variables:

```
questions_shuffled = list(questions.keys())
random.shuffle(questions_shuffled)
correct = 0
```

#### For each question, get the input and check if it's correct:

```
for n, question in enumerate(questions_shuffled):
    print(f"Question {n + 1}:")
    answer = input(question).strip().lower()
    if answer == questions[question].lower():
        print("Correct")
        correct += 1
    else:
        print(f"Incorrect, the right anser is {questions[question]}")
```

#### Print the final result:

```
print(f"You got {correct} out of {len(questions)} correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

qList = [{'q':"What is the capital of England?", 'a': "London"},
         {'q':"What is the capital of France?", 'a': "Paris"},
         {'q':"What is the capital of Germany?", 'a': "Berlin"}]

random.shuffle(qList)
score = 0

for indx,question in enumerate(qList):
    print("\n\nQuestion " + str(indx) + "\n")
    ans = str(input(question['q'] + "\n"))
    if ans == question['a']:
        print("\nCorrect")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("\nIncorrect")
print("You scored", score, "out of 3 correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

q = [ ("What is the capital of England?", "London"),
      ("What is the capital of France?", "Paris"),
      ("What is the capital of Germany?", "Berlin")
    ]

random.shuffle(q)
score = 0

for n, (question, correct_answer) in enumerate(q):
    print("\n\nQuestion %d\n" % (n+1))
    answer = input(question + "\n")
    if answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
       print("\nCorrect")
       score += 1
    else:
       print("\nIncorrect")

print("\nYou scored %d correct out of %d questions!" % (score, len(q)))
```